# Getting results from ARIMA model

Tags: python, dataframe, arima

I am using the following code from Kaggle to evaluate parameters, create a model using the best ones as defined by lowest AIC, and then output the summary of the attempts. This runs without error until I create the dataframe and try to populate with results.  When I run the lines to create the results_table, I get the error: ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 2 elements.  If I create an empty df, the columns appear, but then the variable best_model isn't defined and I can't get my summary.  It's like something's wrong with the results data I'm trying to create and pass. Thoughts?

Thanks,
Benny

```
# Initial approximation of ARIMA parameters
Qs = range(0, 2)
qs = range(0, 3)
Ps = range(0, 3)
ps = range(0, 3)
D=1
d=1
parameters = product(ps, qs, Ps, Qs)
parameters_list = list(parameters)
len(parameters_list)

# Model Creation - Parameter Selection done using the X_train dataset which has gone through scaling
results = []

best_aic = float("inf")
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
for param in parameters_list:
    try:
        model=sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(X_train, order=(param[0], d, param[1]),
                                        seasonal_order=(param[2], D, param[3], 12)).fit(disp=-1)
    except ValueError:
        print('Sub-optimal parameters:', param)
        continue
    aic = model.aic
    if aic < best_aic:
        best_model = model
        best_aic = aic
        best_param = param
    results.append([param, model.aic])

# Best ARIMA models/parameter review

result_table = pd.DataFrame(results)
result_table.columns = ['parameters', 'aic']

print(result_table.sort_values(by = 'aic', ascending=True).head())
print(best_model.summary())
```

Comment: Actual error: `ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-21d73d800a0a> in <module>()
     32 
     33 result_table = pd.DataFrame(results)
---> 34 result_table.columns = ['parameters', 'aic']
     35 
     36 print(result_table.sort_values(by = 'aic', ascending=True).head())

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 2 elements`